# A generic error occurred in GDI+ when taking a screenshot

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, screenshot

A generic error occurred in GDI+ when taking a screenshot. User account has write access to folder, I don't understand why I'm getting this, the code is below:

```
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   string baseurl = "http://localhost:53532";

   String ourPath = "~/visual studio 2015";
   String testTitle = ourPath + "test.txt";
   String testScreenshotTitle = ourPath + "test.jpg";

   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseurl);


   ITakesScreenshot screenshotDriver = driver as ITakesScreenshot;
   Screenshot screenCapture = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();
   screenCapture.SaveAsFile(testScreenshotTitle, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: a)sure about the '~' ? b) which line throws the error?

Comment: @TaW when I use C:\\test.jpg I get "illegal characters in path"
b)  screenCapture.SaveAsFile(testScreenshotTitle, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

Comment: It currently tries to save to `~/visual studio 2015test.jpg` - You may want to use `Path.Combine()`.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis it really worked, I just used it incorrectly on the first try

Comment: @ŽygimantasDirma I don't know what you mean with "it worked" - is `~/visual studio 2015test.jpg` the _exact_ path to which you _want_ to save your file?

Answer (score 0):

Does the folder `~` exist in the current directory?

Point: On windows, the `~` does not have a special meaning of "home directory" as it does on Linux. You need to specify the actual path.